# Visual Studio build with batch without hardcoding paths

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

I've got a public git repository and I want to add a batch file that would automatically build the solution using VisualStudio. This means I don't want to hardcode the paths there as different users might use different versions of VisualStudio. Is there a way to check for the existing VS installations and use the newest version?

I know that `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\%VERSION%` could be used, but I don't know how to loop through the versions and use latest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [vswhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere) to query a specific visual studio version.

Find the latest version:

```
vswhere -latest
```

Find the latest version within a certain range 14.0 (2015) to 15.* (2017):

```
vswhere -version [14.0,16.0)
```

This uses the same syntax as NuGet uses for dependencies.

To capture the location in a batch file, use:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%i in (`vswhere -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild`) do (
  if /i "%%i"=="installationPath" set InstallDir=%%j
)
```

To find a version that includes a specific feature, use the `-requires` option. The above option searches for a version that ships with MsBuild.